# Background color based on actual Barcelona time-zone and Also elements change too

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the time of your computer and based on the hour change the body background to a specific color. I also have an image in the middle of the html file inside a div and I want to replace the image's background based on hours.

```
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
var psj=0;
//18-19 night
if (hours > 17 && hours < 20){
    document.write('<body bgcolor="orange" text="#FFFFFF">')
}
//20-21 night
if (hours > 19 && hours < 22){
    document.write('<body bgcolor="orangered" text="#FFFFFF">')
}
//22-4 night
if (hours > 21 || hours < 5){
    document.write
    ('<body bgcolor="black" text="#FFFFFF">')
}
//9-17 day
if (hours > 8 && hours < 18){
    document.write('<body bgcolor="deepskyblue" text="#FFFFFF">')
}
//7-8 day
if (hours > 6 && hours < 9){
    document.write('<body bgcolor="skyblue" text="#FFFFFF">')
}
//5-6 day
if (hours > 4 && hours < 7){
    document.write('<body bgcolor="steelblue" text="#FFFFFF">')
}
```

---

```
<div id="main-img">
    <img src="images/img1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I also want this script to work based on Barcelona, Spain only. any help to get that done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this js, to change `src` of image:

```
$('#main-img > img').attr('src','NewImage.png');
```

... placed in the right if-else structure ... thats it.

*PS: this is based on jQuery*

You could also clean up your if-else-structure like this:

```
if( hours>17 && hours<20 ){//18-19 night
    $('body').css({'background-color':'orange','color':'#FFF'});
    $('#main-img > img').attr('src','18_19.png');
} else if(hours>19 && hours<22 ){//20-21 night
    $('body').css({'background-color':'orangered','color':'#FFF'});
    $('#main-img > img').attr('src','20_21.png');
} else if( hours>21 || hours<5 ){//22-4 night
    $('body').css({'background-color':'black','color':'#FFF'});
    $('#main-img > img').attr('src','22_04.png');
} else if( hours>8 && hours<18 ){//9-17 day
    $('body').css({'background-color':'deepskyblue','color':'#FFF'});
    $('#main-img > img').attr('src','09_17.png');
} else if( hours>6 && hours<9 ){//7-8 day
    $('body').css({'background-color':'skyblue','color':'#FFF'});
    $('#main-img > img').attr('src','07_08.png');
} else {//5-6 day
    $('body').css({'background-color':'steelblue','color':'#FFF'});
    $('#main-img > img').attr('src','05_06.png');
}
```

Comment: Hi Ole! The #main-img one seems not to be working:( even the background-color one is not working on that previous example. why:(?